# Going from a for loop to a list comprehension

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have a program that displays and inventory report and i was just wondering how I could put the following into a list comprehension instead of a for-loop...I'm kind of a noob at all this python jargon but from what i know is that anything that is in the form of a for-loop can also be expressed as a list comprehension....ANY help would be appreciated

```
def rowSum(TotSize,data,row,col):
    """Calculates the sum of each row in a given 2 dimensional list and stores
it into a given one dimensional list"""
    for i in range(row):
        sum = 0
        for j in range(col):
            sum += data[i][j]
        TotSize[i] = sum
```

Comment: Do you really want a list comprehension?  This looks like a job for `map` and `sum` to me (although `map` and list comprehensions are really just different ways of expressing the same idea).

Comment: "*anything that is in the form of a for-loop can also be expressed as a list comprehension*" - This is not really true. Any list, where its elements can be **explicitly** defined by a function of another list, can be written as a list comprehension: `newList = [f(x) for x in otherList]`. This is equivalent to `map` in many languages: `newList = otherList.map(f)`. Some lists cannot be easily represented this way, like 1D cellular automata, 2D dynamic programming tables, or functions with side-effects (like the `sum` in your rowSum). (You'd write sums like you do, or use `reduce`)

Comment: "and stores it into <a passed-in parameter>" - don't do that. Return values using the return value.

Comment: By `2 dimensional list` do you mean list like this:[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]],and not this:[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is essentially equivalent to

```
TotSize[:] = map(sum, data)
```

This will sum over all of `data`, not only the first `row` rows and the firs `col` cols.  It will also resize `TotSize` to match the number of rows `data` has (assuming `TotSize` is a list).

I wonder why you are passing in the list that should store the result.  In Python, you'd usually simply return that list:

```
def row_sums(data):
    return map(sum, data)
```

Now it's questionable whether it's worthwhile to define a function for this at all…

Answer (score 6):

I might have misunderstood your question, but are you asking for something like this?

```
>>> testdata = [[5, 6, 8], [], range(8), [42]]
>>> ToTSize = [sum(row) for row in testdata]
>>> ToTSize
[19, 0, 28, 42]
```